# Read information from output file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a Bash script to read data from a program output. The output format is like the following:

```
Net latency average = 55.3649
minimum = 8
maximum = 577
Packet latency average = 56.3409
minimum = 9
maximum = 567
```

The words average, minimum and maximum are used several times in the output file so the values must be the ones associated with the "Packet latency". I want to store the values in variables in order to do some operations with them and write them back to a file.

I have try with sed and awk but it's a difficult task.

Comment: Please show your code and desired output.

Comment: `read avg min max <<<"$(grep -A 2 'Packet latency average' input.txt | awk '{ORS=" "; print $NF}')"`

Comment: @twalberg Your solution it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ packetLatencyMin=$(sed -n '/Packet latency/,/^[A-Z]/{s/minimum = \(.*\)/\1/p}' file)
$ packetLatencyMax=$(sed -n '/Packet latency/,/^[A-Z]/{s/maximum = \(.*\)/\1/p}' file)
$ echo $packetLatencyMin
9
$ echo $packetLatencyMax
567
```

Comment: Almost. It works for the integers (minimum and maximum) but it doesn't work for the floating point (average). In addition I have found another problem I get two results because the output file is redundant
 6
 6 (1 samples)
How can I select only the first one?

Answer (score 1):

With ex:

```
$ cat input.txt 
Net latency average = 55.3649
minimum = 8
maximum = 577
Packet latency average = 56.3409
minimum = 9
maximum = 567
$ cat latency.sh
#!/bin/bash

ex input.txt << EOM
/Packet latency average
normal kdgg4dwj2dwj2dwA
wq
EOM
$ ./latency.sh
$ cat input.txt
56.3409
9
567
```

ex scripts allow you to modify files using commands similar to VIM, so they're pretty useful if you already know VIM.